# I want to display the alert box but for a certain interval. is it possible in javascript or in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Right now i am using java-script to display alert message box. it contains ok button if i click the button then only it hides .But my requirement is to display it only for few seconds then it should automatically close and redirect to my page.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Enter Mandatory fields");document.location='productsegment.php';
</script>
 <?
```

Comment: perfect which u want : http://www.jquerydemo.dailyfreecode.com/jqueryui_examples/dialogonfly.aspx

Comment: Instead of alert , use div box to show message and you can set hide time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) function rather then the alert because it can be easiarly controlled and you cant auto close an alert. see link below

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.fi/2012/02/how-to-open-and-auto-close-jquery-ui.html

Below is a code example from the link above

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });

 setTimeOut(function() {
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" )
 }, 5000);



 </script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be           moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for plain JavaScript. So the flow would be, assuming you had a form previously entered that had an empty mandarory field:

1. Check if mandatory field is empty
2. If so, call a function that shows a warning, `warn()` in our example. Better in a form of a [tooltip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) or maybe a [modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)
3. Have that custom tooltip/modal hide after `n` seconds
4. redirect

And so:

```
function warn(){
    //show modal/tooltip
    setTimeout(function(){
        //hide modal/tooltip after 5000ms
        window.location = 'productsegment.php';
    },5000);
}

//call warn when you determined that mandatory field is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, most other answers are basically wrong!

It's **not possible** to show an `alert()` for only a few seconds; once shown, **only user interaction can close it**.

For messages that should automatically close you could use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use timer, setTimeout().